# Suggest structure for query $sumRange(low,high)$ which returns sum of elements whose key $k$ satisfies $low \le k \le high$ in $\Theta(\log n)$ time

Tags: data-structures

> Suggest a data structure to perform a query $sumRange(low,high)$ which will return the sum of the elements whose key $k$ satisfies $low \le k \le high$ in $\Theta(\log n)$ time.

I found the original problem [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-bst-nodes-that-are-in-a-given-range/) (although it's for counting) but it runs in $\Theta(n)$ time. However, I think with additional data structures and/or improvements this can be done in $\Theta(\log n)$.

I think we need a balanced binary search tree, for example, red-black tree.

Then I thought of the following algorithm:

```
sumRange(low, high) 
sum <- 0
temp
closestToLow <- findClosest(low)

if(low=closestToLow)
    sum += closestToLow.key

temp <- successor(closestToLow)
sum += temp.key
```

It will only find the `low` point and its successor. I guess we need a similar piece of code to find the `high` point. Not sure how to traverse in between though.

Answer (score 3):

[Prefix sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) or a 1-D [summed area table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) suffice to answer those queries in $O(1)$ time.  (Alternatively, you can augment a balanced binary search tree -- I will let you discover how.)

Comment: Yes I also though of augmenting the tree with sum field. So intuitively I think we can get the sum of the high bound - sum of low bound but we may take too much this way. So for example all elements to the left of low should be discounted